# Find the table entry with the largest number, only if it matches a condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table like below and I want to return the name of the item with the greatest effect of a particular type. For example, I want the name of the ring with the best 'Shield' enchantment, in this case 'Brusef Amelion's Ring'.

| Description | Apparel slot | Effect Type | Effect Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apron of Adroitness | Chest | Fortify Agility | 5 pts |
| Brusef Amelion's Ring | Ring | Shield | 18% |
| Cuirass of the Herald | Chest | Fortify Health | 15 pts |
| Fortify Magicka Pants | Legs | Fortify Magicka | 20 pts |
| Grand ring of Aegis | Ring | Shield | 6% |

I've tried using a MAXIFS statement:

```
=maxifs(Effect Value, Apparel Slot, "=Ring", Effect Type, "=Shield")
```

and that returns 0.18, as I'd expect. But I want it to return the name of this item, 'Brusef Amelion's Ring'. So I then tried using a vlookup on this value, but there doesn't seem to be the option to only lookup a value if ('Apparel Slot'='Ring' && 'Effect Type'='Shield'), for example.

I feel like there must be a way of nesting some specific functions here, but I can't quite figure it out.

Is there any way to do this while avoiding manually sorting and filtering my data before running each query?

Comment: It would be easy to do with a script.  But probably not as a cell function. I would probably do it with a custom dialog.

Comment: I couldn't think for the life of me think of a clear title for this question, any suggestions on a clearer title to help others would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=DGET(A1:D6,"Description",{"Apparel slot","Effect Value";"Ring",MAXIFS(D2:D6,B2:B6,"Ring",C2:C6,"Shield")})
```

[DGET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094148?hl=en) function needs column headers to work with as you can see. So we want the value from the column Description. "Originally" this is a DGET function:

```
DGET(A2:F20,"price",{"Ticker";"Google"})
```

This is saying: Find price where ticker = google.

We can enhance this a bit by entering two criteria's this is done , or \ separated (depends on your country settings) like this:

```
DGET(A2:F20,"price",{"Ticker","Year;"Google",2020})
DGET(A2:F20;"price";{"Ticker"\"Year;"Google"\2020})
```

Find price where ticker = google and year = 2020.

Ofcource you can replace "Google" with a cell reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much indeed, really appreciated dude :D